# error: initializing argument 1 of ‘SetIterator<T>::SetIterator(T*) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]’

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new to c++ and I'm doing this GoFish project, but I'm getting the following error message and I just can't fix it. This is the error message:

`week05.cpp: In function ‘void testFind()’:
week05.cpp:241:35: error: cannot convert ‘SetIterator<std::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘int’ in initialization
          int itFind = s1.find(text);
                                   ^
week05.cpp:245:28: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘std::basic_string<char>*’ [-fpermissive]
             s1.erase(itFind);
                            ^
In file included from week05.cpp:17:0:
set.h:93:3: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘SetIterator<T>::SetIterator(T*) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]’ [-fpermissive]
   SetIterator(T* p) : p(p) {}
   ^
make: *** [week05.o] Error 1`

And this is the testFind() function:

```
void testFind()
{
    try
    {
        Set <string> s1;

        // fill the Set with text
        cout << "Enter text, type \"quit\" when done\n";
        string text;
    do
    {
        cout << "\t" << s1 << " > ";
        cin  >> text;
        if (text != "quit")
            s1.insert(text);
    }
    while (text != "quit");

    // make a copy of the set using the copy constructor
    Set <string> s2(s1);

    // look for an item in the set
    cout << "Find items in the set and delete.\n";
    cout << "Enter words to search for, type \"quit\" when done\n";

    cout << "\t" << s1 << " > ";
    cin  >> text;
    do
    {
        int itEmpty = -1;
        int itFind = s1.find(text);
        if (itFind != itEmpty)
        {
            cout << "\tFound and removed!\n";
            s1.erase(itFind);
        }
        else
            cout << "\tNot found\n";
        cout << "\t" << s1 << " > ";
        cin  >> text;
    }
    while (text != "quit");

    // show the list again
    cout << "The remaining set after the items were removed\n";
    cout << "\t" << s1 << endl;

    // show the list before the items were removed
    cout << "The items in the set before the items were removed\n";
    cout << "\t" << s2 << endl;
    }
    catch (const char * sError)
    {
       cout << sError << endl;
    }
  #endif // TEST3
 }
```

and this is in the set.h file, functions find() and erase():

```
template <class T>
SetIterator<T> Set <T> :: find(const T & t) const throw (const char *)
{
    SetIterator<T> loc;
    //Linear Search
    for(loc=begin(); loc!=end(); loc++)
    {
        if(*loc==t)
            return loc;
    }
    return loc;
}


template<class T>
void Set<T> :: erase(SetIterator<T> item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] == *item)
        {
            data[i] = data[--numItems];
        }
    }
    sort();
}
```

I tried putting template  for testFind() and declaring itFind as T instead of int, but then it will say undefined reference.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your `Set::find` function returns a `SetIterator<T>`, where `T` is the type in your set. You're trying to assign a `SetIterator<T>` to an `int`, which isn't possible. You can dereference the iterator to get the value it's pointing to (`*it`), but as you have a set of `string`s, that'll give you a `string` not an `int`.

You've not provided enough of the `Set` implementation for anyone to give string advice, but you shouldn't be assigning the results of `find` to an `int` - it should be assigned to a `SetIterator<string>` and compared to something of the same type.